# Woocommerce REST API - filter orders by number or date

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to retrieve an order by its number (not order ID) or by a date.

Earlier I've tried to retrieve (with Postman) an order by its `order_id`, `status` or `order_key` - and it worked:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?status=completed&consumer_key=ck_...&consumer_secret=cs_...
```

With the example above, it works correctly. 
However, when I'm trying to use `number`, all of the orders are listed:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?number=123&consumer_key=ck_...&consumer_secret=cs_...
```

I've tried also `filter[number]`, the result is the same (all orders are listed):

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?filter[number]=123&consumer_key=ck_...&consumer_secret=cs_...
```

**Question:** Could you please explain how can I get order by order number (or a date) using Woocommerce REST API?

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, you need to display orders in an ASC or DESC order based on the order number.

you can use `orderby` and `order` query string parameter like this to get the order by date `https://localhost/wp-test/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&orderby=date&order=asc&consumer_key=ck_b9f70548c7b676&consumer_secret=cs_10acfa5ab943eb6a0e`

Generally order by date will provide you the result of an order by number too because the order placed on the latest date will have the latest order id as per WordPress until you modify from the admin side and vice-versa

Please let me know if I can help you further..